# What does "following on" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Please clarify the exact meaning of the bold part in the text below.

> What has landed me here in Hospital is not too serious. I see worse
>   all around me and get my mind off of all that by picturing things and
>   wondering for instance if you are still there in the Library. If you
>   are the one I mean, you are about of medium size or perhaps not quite,
>   with light brownish hair. You came a few months before it was time for
>   me to go in the Army **following on Miss Tamblyn** who had been there
>   since I first became a user aged nine or ten. In her time the books
>   were pretty much every which way, and it was as much as your life was
>   worth to ask her for the least help or anything since she was quite a
>   dragon. Then when you came what a change, it was all put into sections
>   of Fiction and Non-Fiction and History and Travel and you got the
>   magazines arranged in order and put out as soon as they arrived, not
>   left to molder away till everything in them was stale. I felt
>   gratitude but did not know how to say so. Also I wondered what brought
>   you there, you were an educated person.
>   *<sub>"Casting Away" by Alice Munro</sub>*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You came, following Miss Tamblyn. So when Miss Tamblyn left, the new librarian arrived, she was the next one after Miss Tamblyn.

And that happened a few months before the writer had to go to the army. But Miss Tamblyn had nothing to do with the army, even though she was a dragon. :)

Comment: I've troubled you so much today. Thank you very much :)